# React-select & search in options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, drop-down-menu, react-select

I need to make select with search in options.
I know about Select2.js, but i guess this is the wrong decision. I want to do it with react-select, but i dont know how. I have no ideas and I will be glad to any help.

Comment: Example: https://www.syncfusion.com/products/react-js2/control/images/dropdown-list/filtertype.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [example](https://react-select.com/advanced#experimental) which looks very similar to what you're after on the advanced section of the `react-select` docs. It requires a lot of customisation but it seems possible.

Here's the code they provide in the docs:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { Component } from 'react';
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core';
import Button from '@atlaskit/button';

import Select from 'react-select';
import { defaultTheme } from 'react-select';
import { stateOptions } from '../data';

const { colors } = defaultTheme;

const selectStyles = {
  control: provided => ({ ...provided, minWidth: 240, margin: 8 }),
  menu: () => ({ boxShadow: 'inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)' }),
};

type State = { isOpen: boolean, value: Object };

export default class PopoutExample extends Component<*, State> {
  state = { isOpen: false, value: undefined };
  toggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ isOpen: !state.isOpen }));
  };
  onSelectChange = value => {
    this.toggleOpen();
    this.setState({ value });
  };
  render() {
    const { isOpen, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <Dropdown
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClose={this.toggleOpen}
        target={
          <Button
            iconAfter={<ChevronDown />}
            onClick={this.toggleOpen}
            isSelected={isOpen}
          >
            {value ? `State: ${value.label}` : 'Select a State'}
          </Button>
        }
      >
        <Select
          autoFocus
          backspaceRemovesValue={false}
          components={{ DropdownIndicator, IndicatorSeparator: null }}
          controlShouldRenderValue={false}
          hideSelectedOptions={false}
          isClearable={false}
          menuIsOpen
          onChange={this.onSelectChange}
          options={stateOptions}
          placeholder="Search..."
          styles={selectStyles}
          tabSelectsValue={false}
          value={value}
        />
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}

// styled components

const Menu = props => {
  const shadow = 'hsla(218, 50%, 10%, 0.1)';
  return (
    <div
      css={{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 4,
        boxShadow: `0 0 0 1px ${shadow}, 0 4px 11px ${shadow}`,
        marginTop: 8,
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 2,
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
const Blanket = props => (
  <div
    css={{
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      position: 'fixed',
      zIndex: 1,
    }}
    {...props}
  />
);
const Dropdown = ({ children, isOpen, target, onClose }) => (
  <div css={{ position: 'relative' }}>
    {target}
    {isOpen ? <Menu>{children}</Menu> : null}
    {isOpen ? <Blanket onClick={onClose} /> : null}
  </div>
);
const Svg = p => (
  <svg
    width="24"
    height="24"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    focusable="false"
    role="presentation"
    {...p}
  />
);
const DropdownIndicator = () => (
  <div css={{ color: colors.neutral20, height: 24, width: 32 }}>
    <Svg>
      <path
        d="M16.436 15.085l3.94 4.01a1 1 0 0 1-1.425 1.402l-3.938-4.006a7.5 7.5 0 1 1 1.423-1.406zM10.5 16a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11z"
        fill="currentColor"
        fillRule="evenodd"
      />
    </Svg>
  </div>
);
const ChevronDown = () => (
  <Svg style={{ marginRight: -6 }}>
    <path
      d="M8.292 10.293a1.009 1.009 0 0 0 0 1.419l2.939 2.965c.218.215.5.322.779.322s.556-.107.769-.322l2.93-2.955a1.01 1.01 0 0 0 0-1.419.987.987 0 0 0-1.406 0l-2.298 2.317-2.307-2.327a.99.99 0 0 0-1.406 0z"
      fill="currentColor"
      fillRule="evenodd"
    />
  </Svg>
```

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bhabha-2mpiq?fontsize=14)